# Java abstract inheritance in nested classes

Tags: java

Does Java allow to do something similar to this:

Abstract.java:

```
public abstract class Abstract {
    int state;
    abstract void changeState(int newState);
    public static class Inherited extends Abstract {
        void changeState (int newState) {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

Base.java:

```
public class Base {
    static HashMap<String, Abstract> map;
    static {
        map.insert("handle", new Abstract.Inherited());
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get: "The method insert(String, Abstract.Inherited) is undefined for the type HashMap String,Abstract". I know I can resolve it by moving Inherited completely out of Abstract, but is there a way to preserve it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your classes. There is no `insert` method in `HashMap` class. What you need is `put()` method.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the question as asked isn't related the actual problem causing the compiler error.


Comment: @user1212010 You said that you "can resolve it by moving Inherited completely out of Abstract."  How did that resolve it, if the issue was that `HashMap` doesn't have an `insert` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with nested classes, and everything to do with the fact that the method in `Map` is called `put`, not `insert`.

What you're trying to do is entirely valid. After changing `insert` to `put` and importing `java.util.HashMap` in `Base.java`, your code compiles.

Comment: Arrgh. Thanks, my fault.